# How to go from local .Net server to Unity

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine

So I have created a server using .Net and Entity Framework that connects to my AWS RDS Microsoft SQL Server. I am using this for a backend in my newest Unity game.

I have tested it by running POST and GET urls in Postman. Logging in and registering works!
When I test I use the URL www.localhost: https://localhost:7254/authentication/register

**What I don't understand is when I implement this into my game, what will the URL be?
ex) https://www./authentication/register**

I do not understand how to go from running this server local to global. Can users devices use their own local host? (This seems unlikely). I am thinking that I should deploy my server as a web app and attach it to my RDS if thats even possible. I am just unsure of the next steps.

I cannot find a lot of resources on this and I am not a data engineer. Just trying to learn the ocean of knowledge required to be an indie game dev.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

I have tried to use UnityWebRequest to send GET and POST urls but this is not working as I have no way of using a URL that will work for every device.

Comment: Well you will need to HOST your server somewhere (like AWS, Azure, etc) so that you get a public Domain/URL you can actually connect to via internet .. see e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html

Comment: Or you need a fixed IP and can run it from your machine

Comment: @derHugo so I will deploy my .net app to aws, should I used elatic beanstalk?

Comment: @derHugo and should I use IPv4 elastic address?